# web control of .net windows form application cant open web.whatsapp.com

Tags: c#, winforms, web-controls

Hi I've been doing this project using .Net C# windows form application , I need to open whats app's web link In one of my form 
I tried using web control but when i tried to run the application the URL suggested list of browser saying my browser isn't supported.
I tried CefSharp as well but there was an issue regarding the architecture which i couldn't fix

Comment: Try using WPF. Or something else that is not as ancient as WinForms.

Comment: Have you tried using webbrowser constrol?

Comment: If CEF isnt working try this one: https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home

Comment: @Mathew I tried WPF as well , i think the problem is with web control

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid  i didn't get that !

Comment: WebBrowser is a built in control which you can use  in your winforms for websites to open in your application.